# Is the article reporting the first cell phone still around?

Tags: engineering

At around the 3 min mark in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C6gNeKjC9Cc, Dr. Martin Cooper, the inventor of the first cell phone says that he made the first phone call on 4/3/73 to impress a journalist. Could anyone provide a link to the article that was written by this journalist?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

rarenewspapers.com/view/596532 Smith, G. (1973, April 4). Motorola Introduces Wire-less Phone. The New York Times, pp. 1,57

Comment: If you just need the text of the article, you can get it from the New York Times website [directly](http://www.nytimes.com/1973/04/04/archives/motorola-introduces-wireless-telephone-motorola-shows-wireless.html?_r=0)